# Android default character encoding

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding

What is the default character encoding of the Android system? Which `Charset` is used?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The default character encoding for Android is UTF-8, as specified by [the JavaDoc of the `Charset.defaultCharset()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()). It can be validated by calling that same method.

Comment: Fortunately, you don't need to run a program to verify it's UTF-8.  The documentation for that method states it outright: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()

Comment: @JayLieske If you want UTF-8 you're still better off by [indicating the encoding directly](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8). That makes the code more portable, and it would protect you against changes of the Android system.

Comment: Actually the android developper website says that String objects are using UTF-16, so what do we mean by android default encoding ? the encoding used in strings for applications or something else ?

Comment: @pgsandstrom Where do you see default mentioned as UTF-8? The provided link doesn't say that!

Comment: @Virus721 actually strings are Unicode UTF-16 is a character encoding, just like UTF-8 or ASCII.  There is an explicit process for converting bytes into the language's String type: the encoding.

Comment: provided link now tells that `defaultCharset` 
> Android note: The Android platform default is always UTF-8.