# How to enable "non-English" input in Android studio EditText?

Tags: java, php, android-studio, android-edittext, arabic

I'm designing an android application and the user can input a Name in EditText.
When I enter the name in English it works, but when I try it in another language like Arabic, in the database it's saved like this: `?????`

How can I make the `EditText` work with Arabic?

Comment: It's not fault of your EditText.

Comment: How you got to know `???` are stored in database. Definitely  you may have logged that. That may be because your IDE and PC doesn't support arabic. EditText has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I'm working in genymotion with xampp localhost so I know what is stored in my database, and my laptop is supporting Arabic :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android default character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207631/android-default-character-encoding)

Comment: please check your database from your devise maybe the problem is in the server, by default android support arabic

Comment: I think you need to change the **character encoding** in your database. (are you using SQLite or some other external DB?)

Comment: I check my DB, I think the problem is with the DB not EditText :( ,, I'm using MySQL database , any help please?

Comment: character encoding is utf-8 ,, I read that the utf-8 support arabic