# How to properly handle string lengths and encodings in Android?

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

#### What am I confused about

Hello, I am currently very confused about the state of charsets and how to best handle them in Android. Sources also seem to provide conflicting information.

1) According to this post, the Java JVM defaults to `UTF-16`
[What is the Java's internal represention for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16)

2) According to this post, the Java JVM (under Android) defaults to `UTF-8`
[Android default character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207631/android-default-character-encoding)
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()

#### What I am currently working with

1) I have an Android application that is `minSdkVersion 17`.

2) It has no settings in its `gradle` file/`manifest` file/any file that specifies any preferences regarding charset or encoding.

3) It uses `AppCompatEditText` and `AppCompatTextView` from `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` some of them constrained with the xml property `android:maxLength="140"`

4) Code that uses `String myText = myView.getText().toString();` to get contents.

5) Code that uses `myView.setText(myText);` to set contents.

6) Code that uses `myText.length();` to measure contents. (e.i. update a "characters remaining" view according to `android:maxLength="140"`)

basically this `remaining.setText(String.valueOf(140 - myText.length()));` hooked up to a `TextWatcher.onTextChanged` event listener

#### What I need help with

1) A way to standardize both Java and Android to use the same charset for my application (either forcing them to use `UTF-16` or `UTF-8` - I don't want to deal with weird corner cases that might arise from working with 2 different charsets (or if the user sets the defaults to something different - can they even do that? IDK WHAT IS GOING ON AAAAAAAAAH)

2) A way to standardize behavior of `android:maxLength="140"` and `remaining.setText(String.valueOf(140 - myText.length()));` - I don't know what Android does under the hood with `android:maxLength`, and I need to ensure that `remaining.setText(String.valueOf(140 - myText.length()));` doesn't come back negative because maybe `android:maxLength` doesn't use `String.length();` but some other weird codepoint measuring system.

3) A way to properly encode and decode `String myText` data to and from HTTPS to backend Django servers.

Sorry if the question is bad or vague. I'm just really drowning in charset hell right now. I just need some sort of straight forward checklist to just make things "work" in Android right now...

Comment: Is this just an academic question, or are you encountering an actual issue?  If so, what is it exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think it is good practice to only deal with a software problem until something blows up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android JVM is still a Java JVM, and so it has to follow the Java spec, and that spec says that `char` is 2 bytes and `String` uses UTF-16 for its *public interface*, regardless of the *internal representation* of the character data in memory. This is stated in Peter's answer to [What is the Java's internal represention for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/) that you linked to.

Charsets don't apply to `String`-only operations, like accessing characters, assigning `String` values, etc.  Everything inside the Java app is UTF-16.  Charsets only apply to serialization operations when converting between `String` and bytes, such as during file I/O, network I/O, etc.  Things where `String` data enters/leaves the Java app.

Comment: is `String.length();` returning the number of Unicode extended grapheme clusters (e.i. what a human would interpret as a character) or the number of `UTF-16` code points? What about `android:maxLength`?

Comment: Neither. They represent the number of `char` elements in a `String`, ie the number of UTF-16 **code units**, not **code points** (`String` has methods for working with codepoints, like `codePointAt`, `codePointBefore`, `codePointCount`, `offsetByCodePoint`, etc).

Comment: So `String.length();` returns number of `UTF-16 code units` and `android:maxLength="140"` bounds the `UTF-16 code units` to less than or equal to 140? So 140 16 bit code units?

Comment: @AlanSTACK: yes. Anything that refers to "characters" is in terms of UTF-16 code units, not codepoints or grapheme clusters (unless stated otherwise)

Comment: Last clarification. So Java uses `UTF-16` internally. Even though `defaultCharset()` returns `UTF-8`. And it only uses `UTF-8` when it needs to serialize it - like writing JSON to disk for example. Am I correct?

Comment: @AlanSTACK: Java's `String` uses a UTF-16 interface (though it might not actually be UTF-16 in memory, if it can be compacted to use Latin-1 without any data loss). `Charset` is used for things like serialization, not normal `String` operations.